# как динамически изменить слой обьекта с изменением всех дочерных обьектов в unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

я хочу изменить слой одного объекта и всех child объектов в unity.

попробовал изменить с :   gameobject.layer = 0;     но он изменил слой который этот скрипт прикреплён, а мне хотелось чтоб код изменил все слои child объектов.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Пройдись рекурсией по потомкам объекта. Но если тебе это нужно, скорее всего ты делаешь что-то не то.

Answer (score 0):

Это задача на [обход дерева](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0), т. е. посещения всех его узлов, в твоём случае узел - это трансформация.

Общий алгоритм такой:

1. Заводим хранилище, где будем хранить (запоминать) трансформации,
   которые надо обработать.
2. Помещаем туда стартовую трансформацию.
3. Извлекаем трансформацию из хранилища.
4. Делаем с ней что нужно.
5. Её детей помещаем (запоминаем) в хранилище.
6. Повторяем с пункта 3.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

void SetLayer (Transform root, int layer)
{
    //хранилище, где будем хранить (запоминать) трансформации с которыми надо отработать
    Queue<Transform> queue = new Queue<Transform>();

    queue.Enqueue(root); //помещаем первую трансформацию с которой начнём

    while (queue.Count > 0) //пока в хранилище есть трансформации для работы...
    {
        Transform current = queue.Dequeue(); //...извлекаем трансформацию для работы из хранилища

        current.gameObject.layer = layer; //...делаем, что нужно, в твоём случае - устанавливаем слой

        //...запоминаем всех детей текущей трансформации
        foreach (Transform child in current)
        {
            queue.Enqueue(child);
        }
    }
}
```